# Python File Manipulation with "virtual file"

Tags: python-3.x, file, txt

basically I'm trying to create an example of file manipulation in Python, and it works great. But the file never shows up in the folder.

Already tried to create with ".txt" in the end and without it, but nothing changes.

Also tried to create mannually an file with the name that I use on the script, but just ignores it and work with this invisible one. But if I try to find this invisible file by hand tiping it on the folder, I got a message that it doesn't exists.

This is an example of my last try:

```
f = open("semt","a")
f.write("Texto a mais")
f.close

f = open("semt","r")
print(f.read())
print(f.readline(2))
print(f.readlines())
f.close
```

Comment: It should be `f.close()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it wasn't the error. I was running it on the VSCode, so it looks like it create a virtual file for debug or something like that. If I run the script directly by the interpretter, it works fine!